# Iterating 1D array and getting 2D tile position

Tags: c#, 2d, algorithm, tiles

I know I'm missing something very obvious here, but I have a 1D array that contains integers.I have a map that is 30 x 30 and the center coordinate is 0,0 (This is actually 3D, but I'm essentially removing the Y-axis). Because of this offset, my loop is from -15 to 14, rather than 0 to 29. Is this incorrect?

I'd like to iterate through the array and if the integer is "1", then I'd like to call `AddSphere(x,y,z)` with the correct `x` and `z` values. How would I get the correct values for x and z? The file is designed to be read left to right rather than left to right, right to left, left to right etc... (although if that's a better approach, I can just change the data to match that style).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to split the integer into two values between `0` and `29` (this is done using integer division and modulus) then offset them by `-15`:

```
for (int n = 0; n < 30 * 30; ++n)
{
    if (Array[n] == 1)
    {
        int x = n % 30 - 15;
        int y = 0;
        int z = n / 30 - 15;

        AddSphere(x, y, z);
    }
}
```

Note that `-15..14` is asymmetrical. If you want `(0,0)` to be at the exact centre of your map, you need an odd value instead of `30`.

Comment: Thank you! The asymmetrical aspect also explains why my attempts ended up with a cube overlapping on the edge, or starting slightly in from it.